# Is there some way to configure timeout properties of a self-hosted Owin app running on Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, owin

We're running a self-hosted Owin application in a Docker container that's using mono:5.4 as it's base image. We've experienced a few timeouts that I think are from infrastructure outside of the Docker container, but I'd like to verify this by adjusting the TimeoutManager settings on the OwinHttpListener. However, when I attempt to get the TimeoutManager from the listener like this:

```
var listener = (OwinHttpListener) appBuilder.Properties["Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener"];
var timeoutManager = listener.Listener.TimeoutManager;
```

I get a `System.NotImplementedException`. I checked in the Mono source, and it is indeed not implemented: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpListener.cs#L135

Is there some other mechanism for configuring how requests will timeout when running a self-hosted Owin application on Mono?

Comment: why not trying to implement it yourself? (this is opensource) plus, you can now look at Microsoft's .NET framework sources, to know how to do it (in fact these sources are a subtree in Mono so you could even make use of them directly in your PullRequest)